# Javascript - How to save exact whitespace count between words from textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to save exact whitespace count between words from textarea when putting it's value into html?

```
<textarea>word "10 whitespaces here" word "20 whitespaces here" word</textarea>
```

html:

```
<div style="width:50px;overflow:hidden;">word "10 whitespaces here" word "20 whitespaces here" word</div>
```

So that all text inside div would be visible.

Comment: Why do you want to replace whitespaces, and what do you want to replace them with?

Comment: What's wrong with leaving the spaces as spaces?

Comment: Have you tried examples? I want to save exact count of whitespaces that user have inputed in textarea.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Well, if you just want to avoid line-breaks, *CSS* is your best friend here:</strike>

```
body {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Of course it's probably not a great idea to set that property to the `document.body`, but you could display the value in some `div node` and give that element the *nowrap*.

Do it like this:

```
var foo = "<textarea>aefawefawef      dqwfawe        fawef awef awefawef awef awef awe fawe</textarea>";


var sp = foo.split(/\s/).filter(function(elem) {
    return !!elem;
}).join('nbsp;');

console.log(sp);
```

This will `.split()` the string after each *whitespace* and filter all empty results. After that is done, it joins the new array with `nbsp;`. That way, you get rid of the multiple whitespace characters (plus, this should be faster than **any** regexp solution can be).

---

```
jQuery(document.body).append(jQuery('<textarea>aefawefawef      dqwfawe        fawef awef awefawef awef awef awe fawe</textarea>').val().split(/\s/).filter(function(elem) { return !!elem; }).join('nbsp;');
```

Comment: I want to avoit solid string. Btw you have mistake in your code &nbsp; not nbsp; nbsp; is a non breaking character, character that prevents an automatic line break. So the line becomes unbreakable/solid and if it's larger than element width in which it will be placed later on, it surely will overflow it, but i want to avoid it and save all whitespaces that user have inputed. If the user wants 10 whitespaces in a row between words, then it should be the same in html afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing "2" spaces with your original code:

```
$('div').html($('textarea').text().replace("  ", " &nbsp;", "g"));
```

Comment: How this is related to my question mate? :D

Comment: Sorry I don't think I'm clear about the question. Do you mean that you can't get the contents of a textarea into another html element while preserving the whitespace? Also, why do you want to avoid a solid string? It will still render the correct number of spaces.

Comment: Try it yourself mate. My examples are working in firebug if jQuery is loaded ofc or jQuerify plugin is installed. Why i don't want it to be solid? Because it will overflow the html element and overflow:hidden will hide the rest of user inputed text. It will place 1 whitespace, even if there were 10 of them between words.

Answer (score 0):

Can you separate out the ''?  This does not necessarily fix your problem, but that textarea is really a constant that shouldn't be subject to the whims of replace.

```
var text = 'aefawefawef      dqwfawe        fawef awef awefawef awef awef awe fawe'.replace(' ','&nbsp;');
jQuery('body').append(jQuery('<textarea>'+text+'</textarea>').val());
```